# CTest, VS2010. How to get rid of Nightly, NightlyMemCheck, etc?

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, ctest

I'm using CMake and CTest with Visual Studio 2010.

After `ENABLE_TESTING()` and several `ADD_TEST()`s my solution contains projects with names 'Continuous', 'Experimental' and others.

I don't need them all. Moreover, I'm going to pass all the code to a person, which is not very familiar with CMake and afraid that this abundance will confuse and mislead him.

So, I'd like to leave only RUN_TESTS project and get rid of all other testing projects.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Double check that there is no [`include(CTest)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/CTest.html) in one of your CMake list files. The inclusion of this CMake module creates the targets *Continuous*, *Experimental*, ... as a side effect. Calling [enable_testing](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/enable_testing.html) is sufficient for getting a `RUN_TESTS` target.

Comment: Indeed, this did the trick. I had `include(CTest)` and then `enable_testing()`